# For loop skips as counter increase

Tags: c, for-loop

I wanna write a program that gets data about student name, grades and birthday and save it into a structure. I have written a "for loop" to do so, but my loop does not work properly as i increases.
*EDIT*:
So my loop works good with i=0 but as i gets higher (i=1) it does not scan the info properly.

inputs:

```
       name:a
       birthdate:79/4/18
       grades:20 20 20
       name:b
       birthdate:76/12/2
       grades:16 13 19

       Output:
       Enter student's name: a
       Enter student's birthday(y/m/d): 79 4 18 
       Enter student's grades: 20 
       Enter student's grades: 20 
       Enter student's grades: 20 
       Enter student's name: 
       Enter student's birthday(y/m/d): 
       b
       Enter student's grades: 
       Enter student's grades: 
       Enter student's grades:
```

**

```
       #include <stdio.h>

    struct date
    {
        int year;
        int month;
        int day;
    };
    typedef struct
    {
        char name[30];
        float grade[3];
        struct date birthdate;
    }student;

    int main()
    {
        student list[2];
        int i,j;
        for(i=0;i<2;i++)
        {
            printf("Enter student's name:\n");
            gets(list[i].name);
            printf("Enter student's birthday(y/m/d):\n");
            scanf("%d%d%d",&list[i].birthdate.year,&list[i].birthdate.month,&list[i].birthdate.day);
            for(j=0;j<3;j++)
            {
                printf("Enter student's grades:\n");
                scanf("%f",&list[i].grade[j]);
            }

        }
return 0;
       }
```

Comment: Can you please show any "crash" output?

Comment: And also show your the input. [Edit] the question and put all clarifications _there_

Comment: *"Enter student's name: Enter student's birthday(y/m/d): b"* when b should be the name. I'm sure this has to do with the character `\n` eaten by scanf

Comment: @Jabberwocky thank you, I just added input and explained my problem more clear.

Comment: when you enter the last grade (`20<ENTER>`) the number is taken from the input buffer but the newline stays there. That newline is used to read a blank string for the next user name. Solution: **always use `fgets()` for user input**.

Comment: @Cid thank you and yes you are right, But as I enter date after "Enter student's birthday" it goes straight to scanning grades and it never scans the name

Comment: Why does your question title say "crash" when that does not appear to be what your program is doing? It seems to be skipping input not crashing. Makes it a bit confusing.

Comment: @kaylum oh you are right I'll fix it now

Comment: @pmg thank you, I tried it but still same problem

Comment: @Ava: did you try `fgets()` for the date? for **everything**? You may want to follow-up with `sscanf()` as in `if (!fgets(input, sizeof input, stdin)) exit(EXIT_FAILURE); if (sscanf(input, "%d", &date) != 1) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should do:

```
scanf("%d/%d/%d", &list[i].birthdate.year, &list[i].birthdate.month, &list[i].birthdate.day);
```

Instead of:

```
scanf("%d%d%d",&list[i].birthdate.year,&list[i].birthdate.month,&list[i].birthdate.day);
```

**Warning:** Do not use `gets()`, it's dangerous. You may replace that syntax as follows:

```
fflush(stdin); // MUST REQUIRED OR INPUT WILL BE SKIPPED
fgets(list[i].name, 30, stdin);
```

> **Sample Output:**

```
Enter student's name:
a
Enter student's birthday(y/m/d):
2003/03/05
Enter student's grades:
12
Enter student's grades:
35
Enter student's grades:
66
Enter student's name:
b
Enter student's birthday(y/m/d):
2005/02/01
Enter student's grades:
44
Enter student's grades:
88
Enter student's grades:
5
```

Comment: Beware: `fgets(list[i].name, 30, stdin);` is not quite the same as `gets(list[i].name);`. With `fgets` you get the `\n`at the end of the string, but not with `gets`

Comment: The function gets() is considered dangerous, rather than that, I used fgets().

Comment: thank you, I tried it but still, the same problem happens, But I used "scanf("%s",&list[i].name);" and the problem was solved, is it okay to use scanf for string?

Comment: @Ava Sorry, I've edited my code. I had made a mistake unknowingly. Use `fflush(stdin)` **before** `fgets()` not **after**.